# Timestamp comparing in timestamp range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, date-range

I currently have 2 timestamp fields in my RubyOnRails database defined as:

```
starttime:timestamp
endtime:timestamp
```

I want to write a simple function in my controller which will take the **current time** and **return TRUE if it lies in the range of the starttime & endtime**.

How I can do this?

Comment: You're really using timestamp and not datetime? Do you want your test to be inclusive or exclusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have an model setup for these, you could do something like this:

```
def currently_in_range(model)
   now = DateTime.now
   model.starttime < now && now < model.endtime
end
```

You should probably put it in the model's class, though. Something like:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   def current?
     now = DateTime.now
     starttime < now && now < endtime
   end
   ...
 end
```

Then in your controller you can just call `model.current?`

Comment: I'd do `def current?(now=DateTime.now)` to allow you to pass in a different "now" for testing or historical auditing.  Otherwise you're right on.

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active?
    (starttime..endtime) === Time.now.to_i
  end
end

class YourController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @your_model = YourModel.first
    @your_model.active?
  end
end
```